# Automatically download a file from Google merchant center

Tags: windows, script, download-manager, file-download

I am manually downloading a file from Google merchant center a couple och times a week.

Is there a plugin or app that can make this process automatically? The file is automatically uploaded to Google from the Ecom platform and I don´t have access to it before it is uploaded.

Comment: There are many solutions. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried selenium for Firefox but the file is open in the browser instead of saved to disk. Now i find imacros and is trying it.